# How to trigger UpdatePanel from a GridView TemplateColumn click?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, controls, updatepanel

I have the following case, all my controls on an update panel on the page.

One of these controls is a GridView, this GridView contains a CheckBox on the header template field (to make a check all). The autopostback is true but when the check changed no thing is changed, the update panel has a trigger asynchronous post back for the GridView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to define an ASyncPostBackTrigger like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
 <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="yourCheckBox" />
  </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
...GridView etc
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: but the check box embedded in the template field in my gridview

Comment: have you tried the above code, your checkbox has an ID correct, even if it is a template field

Comment: the check box with the id  (....)couldn't be found , yeah the check box with the correct id

Comment: please Edit:
in the checkbox check changed :put
updatepanel.Update();

Comment: in the check box changed event

Comment: This wont work when the check box is nested inside a template field

Comment: A control with ID 'yourCheckBox' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this bug after searching everywhere and tried the last solution here with no success. So I first created an OnClick event in the CheckBox. In the Onclick function in the .cs file, make a call to the *SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());* method with arguments as given then just after call the Update method to your UpdatePanel.