# How to make a gridView command field button into an ajax update panel PostBackTrigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel

I have a gridview in an ajax  update panel. I have set the different button events as AsyncPostBackTriggers but I want the select button to open a child web page so it has to be a postback. I tried the following:

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="RowCancelingEdit" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="RowEditing" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="RowUpdated" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="RowUpdating" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="Sorted" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" EventName="Sorting" />
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvClients" />
</Triggers>
```

I recieved the following error:" System.ArgumentException: Control with ID 'gvClients' cannot be registered through both RegisterAsyncPostBackControl and RegisterPostBackControl. This can happen if you have conflicting triggers associated with the target control."

I tried accessing the select button from code behind and setting it as a trigger.

This is the code:

```
   protected void gvClients_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {     
            Button btnDtls = (Button)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];
            string btnDtlsId = btnDtls.ID;
            PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
            trigger.ControlID = btnDtlsId;
            UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        }
    }
```

In debugging I saw that the ID for the button is "ctl01" but I'm getting this error: "A control with ID 'ctl01' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'". Is there a way of accessing a control field select button and setting it as a PostBackTrigger?

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is inside a template, its final id is different and you can get it from the UniqueID property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx

Comment: The button is not in a template, it's a regular command field select button.

Comment: Isn't it inside a grid? The grid has templates. If all buttons in all rows have the same server id, how does the server distinguish between all of them?

Comment: I tried that but recieved the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvClients$ctl02$ctl01' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'."

Comment: Here is another solution. In the button click event write "UpdatePanel1.Update(). look in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552969/howto-trigger-updatepanel-from-a-gridview-templatecolumn-click

Comment: The error is thrown when the grid is being loaded, in the RowDaraBound event. Can code in the click event help here?

Comment: No. The second solution should replace you code. Delete the trigger adding from the RowDataBound event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14132/discussion-between-dov-miller-and-amiram-korach)